# AES decription fails on each 1024th block with 16 wrong bytes

Tags: arrays, go, encryption, sha256, hmac

I am trying to implement a reader is going to decrypt data and validate the data `HMAC + SHA256` at the same time.

Decrypting the complete data as one block and validating it afterward works.

The amount of data can be rather significant, so I don´t want to hold in it in an array.

The reader implementation works for the most part, but **the result of every 1024th AES block is wrong**.

```
func (r *mediaReader) Read(dst []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if m := len(dst); m%r.cbc.BlockSize() != 0 {
        m = (m / r.cbc.BlockSize()) * r.cbc.BlockSize()
        dst = dst[:m]
    }

    n, err = r.limitedReader.Read(dst)

    r.cbc.CryptBlocks(dst, dst)

    tmp := r.fileLength - int64(n)
    if tmp < 0 || err == io.EOF {
        n += int(tmp)
    }
    r.total += n

    r.fileLength -= int64(n)
    r.hash.Write(dst)
    if r.fileLength <= 0 || err == io.EOF {
        //validate
        mac := make([]byte, 10)
        nn, rr := r.fullReader.Read(mac)

        if rr != nil {
            return n, rr
        }

        if nn != 10 {
            return n, fmt.Errorf("not enougth data remaining")
        }

        if !hmac.Equal(mac, r.hash.Sum(nil)) {
            return n, fmt.Errorf("invalid media hmac\n%v\n%v", r.hash.Sum(nil)[:10], mac)
        }
        //SUCCESS
        return n, io.EOF
    }

    return n, err
}
```

The `limitedReader` uses the `fullReader` and ends **10 bytes** before `fullReader` does.

Snippet of `mediaReader` creation:

```
h := hmac.New(sha256.New, macKey)
h.Write(iv)

cbc := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, iv)

media := &io.LimitedReader{R: fullReader, N: length - 10}

return &mediaReader{
    limitedReader: media,
    fullReader:    fullReader,
    hash:          h,
    fileLength:    fileLength,
    cbc:           cbc,
    total:         0,
}
```

> 16384-16399; 1 * 1024 * 16 (AES Blocksize); 16 wrong bytes
>   32768-32783; 2 * 1024 * 16 (AES Blocksize); 16 wrong bytes
>   49152-49167; 3 * 1024 * 16 (AES Blocksize); 16 wrong bytes ...

Does anyone recognize what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If this is a new project and you don't have to consume existing data, consider using [cipher.AEAD](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/#NewGCM). It has proper authentication built in and you can use much larger chunk sizes than 16 bytes, which often improves efficiency.